# The "-cal" suffix

Tags: suffixes

In words **physical**, **mathematical**, **chemical**, etc. Does the **-cal** suffix mean **a matter of** or **belonging to**, or maybe **concerning**?

With what words can we use it and why do some words change when we add **-cal**? Wgat I mean by change is:

- Mathematics - mathematical *(no **s**)*
- Chemistry - chemical *(no **stry**)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no -cal suffix.  There are some words with an -ic suffix and others with -ical.  Usually they mean the same thing.

From the OED:

> **-ic**, *suffix*. **Forms:**  (formerly -ick, ik(e, -ique), primarily forming *adj*s., many of which are used as *n*s. The latter have also the form -ics.

Etymologically, the OED comments:

> In adjs., immediately representing French -ique, < Latin -ic-us, of Latin origin, as in cīvic-us, classic-us, public-us, domestic-us, aquātic-us, or < Greek -ικ-ός, as in κωμικ-ός cōmic-us, γραμματικ-ός grammatic-us, ποιητικ-ός poētic-us. This was in Greek one of the commonest of suffixes, forming adjs., with the sense ‘after the manner of’, ‘of the nature of’, ‘pertaining to’, ‘of’. Its use in Latin was much more restricted,

Adverbially:

> A few adjs. in **-ic** form advs. in -icly, as publicly, franticly,
>   heroicly; but the adv. is usually in **-ically** suffix, from the
>   secondary adj. in **-ical** suffix.

On **-ical**, the OED says:

> Sometimes forming an adjective from a noun in -ic, as music, musical,
>   but more frequently a secondary adjective, as comic, comical,
>   historic, historical. Its origin appears to have been the formation in
>   late Latin of adjectives in -ālis on nouns in -ic-us, or in -icē...
>   In French, adjectives of this type are few, and mostly
>   taken directly from Latin formations, as chirurgical, clérical,
>   grammatical, médical, etc. But in English they are exceedingly
>   numerous...

It elaborates on the **-ic**/**-ical** distinction:

> Many adjectives have a form both in -ic and -ical, and in such cases that in -ical is usually the earlier and that more used. Often also the form in -ic is restricted to the sense ‘of’ or ‘of the nature of’ the subject in
>   question, while that in -ical has wider or more transferred senses,
>   including that of ‘practically connected’ or ‘dealing with’ the
>   subject. Cf. ‘economic science’, ‘an economical wife’, ‘prophetic
>   words’, ‘prophetical studies’, ‘a comic song’, ‘a comical incident’,
>   ‘the tragic muse’, ‘his tragical fate’. A historic book is one
>   mentioned or famous in history, a historical treatise contains or
>   deals with history.

The conclusion is:

> But in many cases this distinction is, from the
>   nature of the subject, difficult to maintain, or entirely
>   inappreciable.

Answer (score 4):

First, you are correct in assuming that **-ical** means **a matter of** or **belonging to**. All definitions you suggested are more or less correct; it simply means **related to the field of**, for example **mathematical**, meaning *related to the field of mathematics*.
The change to which you are referring happens because these words are derived from Latin and Greek roots; *mathematics* from "*mathema*" and *chemistry* from "*khemia*" (these are English approximations of the pronunciation). When modifying these words with suffixes or prefixes, the root is the only part of the word that is always preserved.
The **-cal** suffix may be used with most words ending in **-ic** or, more rarely, **-ry/-y**. See the following examples:

> Electric - Electrical
>   Numeric - Numerical
>   Rhetoric - Rhetorical
>   History - Historical
>   Anatomy - Anatomical

Note that these are all **fields** or **topics**. This rule does not extend to other words, with a few exceptions. Examples of words that **cannot** have **-ical** added as a suffix:

> Moronic - Moronical
>   Icelandic - Icelandical
>   Sophistry - Sophistical

To add to the confusion, there are some **-ical** words that are *technically* valid (dictionaries have entries for them), but are so rare that they are likely to get a few strange looks from people if you use them:

> Atomic - Atomical
>   Ironic - Ironical
>   Rhythmic - Rhythmical

In nearly every instance of this suffix, you will see it used for **fields of study**. There are a few commonly used exceptions to this rule:

> Allegorical
>   Hypothetical
>   Theoretical

There are even more words beyond these that do not take a **-ical** suffix, but an **-al** suffix to mean "related to," but these are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I've no idea why you think that _rhythmical_ is "so rare that [it is] likely to get a few strange looks from people". It accounts for about 10% of uses of _rhythmic/rhythmical_ and was the more common form until about 100 years ago. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rhythmic%2Crhythmical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crhythmic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crhythmical%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Similarly, _ironical_ was the dominant form until about 1935 and still accounts for about 7% of usage. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ironic%2Cironical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cironic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cironical%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: What @DavidRicherby said. I would argue that "rhythmical" (and the adverb "rhythmically" are still the "non-technical" forms of the word, but "rhythmic" is a technical term used in music theory.

Comment: I wonder when somebody will claim the etymology of "anatomical" is "an-atomical" and therefore means "without containing atoms"... ;)

Comment: I have only ever heard or seen "rhythmic" and "ironic." I have also seen "rhythmically" and "ironically," but never "rhythmical" or "ironical." When checking Merriam-Webster to see if these were actually words, both were presented as uncommon variants of "rhythmic" and "ironic." Using both my personal experience and the information provided in the dictionary, I concluded that "rhythmical" and "ironical" are very rarely used, although they are still valid words.